# My relay is getting slower

Tags: fast-relays

Here's a link to the relay in Atlas...
https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/BAF13EDE65C42CF497841AAE7A2CC2598E586817

It has been running for nearly two weeks, except for a reboot yesterday.

Connection: 1Gbps fiber (very little other traffic)
System: Virtual box with 2 cpus and 4GB RAM.  Running on i3 with 16GB

I have not limited the connection speed and the router is a high end Netgear consumer one, so this shouldn't be an issue.

How come the speed is using such a small fraction of what is available and getting even slower?

Answer (score 1):

It takes a while for relays to be fully integrated into the network. The Tor Project has published an excellent blog post called [The lifecycle of a new relay](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay) that has some more details on it.

Comment: Thanks, I'd already seen that article, I knew that utilization would drop on day 8, but didn't expect it to continue to drop for the next 6 days.  I'll wait and see.